# Chrome wont open websocket (wss) from a domain to a subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, wss

I have a domain x.com which is running a web application
There is an MQTT server running on subdomain mqtt.x.com, with websockets / wss all set up,

Using Chrome:

If I head to https://x.com, and run this in console:

`let ws = new WebSocket('wss://mqtt.x.com')`

I get the following error:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://mqtt.x.com/' failed:`

If I go to a completeley different domain (such as stackoverflow.com) and run the command, it works fine.

In firefox/opera/edge, no errors, and it all works fine.

Is there any way to get a more verbose error from chrome?
Or any other idea to resolve this?

**Edit**

Clearing cookies seemed to solve this. still not really sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Cookies seemed to be the answer.